# If public key of two files are same, is it sufficient to conclude that they were signed by the same certificate?

Tags: security, cryptography, x509certificate, public-key-encryption, public-key

I am implementing an auto-update mechanism for my software. The msi on the server is signed using signtool. My app downloads the msi and reads the public key of the downloaded msi. If the public key matches the one that is hard coded in the source code, it will execute the msi and update itself.

Would this is be sufficient to ensure that no malicious msi gets executed by mistake? My understanding is that a file will have the same public key ONLY if signed by my certificate.

**Edit:**
With petey's help, I was able to detect if the msi was signed by my certificate or not. However, this didnt quite solve my problem. I can still edit the signed msi using a tool like Orca. Even the msi is no longer the same as the one that was signed, nothing happens to certificate. So when I check whether the msi is signed by me, I get yes. While I understand that this might be intended behaviour, but **there must be some way to detect if the msi was tampered with??**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Odds are, if it's the same public key, yes it is the same certificate. But with this knowledge an attacker could easily mimic your public key and stick it on his MSI, because, well it's public. You should use that public key to verify the signature on the MSI, not just check if it's the same public key, that way you would be certain it was signed with your corresponding private key, which no attacker would have. You should also run up the cert chain and verify signatures right up to your trusted CA.

Edit:

What exactly are you signing? A signature should not be valid if what was signed is altered. However, it sounds like a Message Authentication Code (keyed hash) would work. If you have a pre-shared hashing key, you could hash the MSI before it is downloaded, then verify the hash again client side. Or if you dont want to use a keyed hash, you could use a regular hash then sign the hash value with that same private key. If you can "verify" (ie decrypt) the hash with the public key, you know that hash came from you, then you can re-hash the msi and check if the hashes are the same.

Comment: Could you share some code on how to perform the necessary checks? I googled and the best I found was to use the Verify() method on the certificate. But as I expressed in the question, I dont think thats what you meant...

Comment: @Amith, rather than using the Verify() method you can build your own certificate chain using the x509chain class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx . This allows you to go through every certificate in the chain and call verify() on each, then check if the 'top' issuer is what you were expecting

Comment: I extract the certificate from the msi. I then build a chain and verify that each element in the chain is valid. Ok. But what do you mean by the top issuer? Secondly, ONLY doing the above, how will it prove that the msi came from me? I believe this only means that the msi came from someone with a valid certificate, that person could be anyone and the msi could be anything.

Comment: @Amith, exaclty, that's why you verify the "top issuer", which would be your CA, check if the DN/thumbprint of the CA cert (at the top of the chain) is your trusted CA. If it is, you know the signature is from a valid certificate issued by your CA. This also allows you to revoke certificates that have been comprimised, and issue new ones to sign code with.

Comment: Am not getting this. Suppose my certificate purchased from godaddy has many elements in the chain with the top issuer being CA1. If you purchase a certificate from go daddy, even you will have the same elements in the chain and the same top issuer. My code should execute the msi only if I have signed it. In the solution you are suggesting, even if you sign the msi, my code will detect that all elements in the chain of YOUR certificate are valid and it will execute the msi. What piece of code/logic is differentiating your certificate from mine?

Comment: @Amith, I was assuming you were the one issueing certs, else you would only check up to the thumbprint/DN of the cert you trust, and only you have access to, in chain. So if you were signing code with a cert directly from go daddy, all you would need to do is check the signature, and the thumbprint+DN of that same cert to know it is yours. Then for a little extra security you could still check if that cert was issued by go daddy. However, in that case, if that cert is compromised you will have to re-compile everything with the thumbprint/DN of the new cert.

Comment: That makes sense. Using the dn and the thumbprint I am able to differentiate between two certificates having the same chain. The thumbprint is supposed to be unique for each certificate, right? Anyway, the next problem am facing is that, I can modify the signed msi using a tool like Orca, and still the thumbprint/dn is the same. I understand that these two are associated with the certificate and not the msi, but there must be a way to detect if the msi was tampered with... Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Got caught up with the day job. Anyway, you have answered all my queries. Thanks!