# Does comparing two assemblies' public keys ensure that they were signed with the same private key?

Tags: .net, signed, public-key

From other questions and articles I've read, it sounds as if a signed assembly has been tampered with, it's hash will be different and it will not be run.  If that's true, then can I conclude that if an unknown assemlbly's public key matches a known assembly's public key, and .net allows the unkown assembly to run, that the unkown assembly was signed with the same key file and that it has not been tampered with?

BTW, I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505204/if-public-key-of-two-files-are-same-is-it-sufficient-to-conclude-that-they-were) but it is asking about a signed MSI and it sounds like that may be a different case than a signed .net assembly.

Edit:  here's my sample code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string unknownAppPath = args[0];
        byte[] unknownKeyBytes = Assembly.LoadFile(unknownAppPath).GetName().GetPublicKey();
        string unknownKeyStr = BitConverter.ToString(unknownKeyBytes);
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        AssemblyName aname = asm.GetName();
        byte[] pubKey = aname.GetPublicKey();
        string hexKeyStr = BitConverter.ToString(pubKey);
        if (hexKeyStr == unknownKeyStr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signed by same private key");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uknown signer!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
```

Further, I read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx) which uses a much more involved method.  I see in the article that he talks about shortcomings of using public key **tokens**, but I don't see why not use the entire public key.  From the answers so far, that sounds like that's what the public key is for... is the problem in that article that you'd have to try to run the assembly?  (he says, "...but you'd be unable to discover this without checking to see if the assembly passes verification.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; that's how public keys work.

You'll also need to make sure that the assembly isn't in the verification skip list; run `sn-Vl` in a VS command prompt.

Comment: Uh... could you expand on that just a bit?  I read a bit about the skip verification list, but it sounds like it makes a snk file without a private key... in that case, the assembly can't be encrypted, right?  But then, does it still have a public key?  It sounds like maybe the skip verification list exists *per machine* and tells .net not to verify those assemblies on that machine - is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Aerik: Correct.  If an attacker has admin access to your machine, he can add the assembly the the skip list and it will appear to be validly signed.

Comment: thanks.  If an attacker has access to my machine, I'm hosed anyway - but I'm glad to have a thorough understanding of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified, the public key can be used to decrypt data encrypted with the private key.  If data could be encrypted with a different private key, then the whole system would be broken.  It's one of the fundamental assertions of public-key cryptography.

Comment: `the public key can be used to decrypt data encrypted with the private key` that's backwards. Also, in this context we are dealing with signing.

Comment: The whole point is that data is encrypted with a private key (hence keyfiles should be kept private), and the public key is the one that is shared, to decrypt it.  Is there something specific to the .NET implementation that you know of that contradicts this?

Comment: Yup, I re-checked a few sources on crypt and .NET details.  Private keys encrypt, public keys decrypt.  .NET builds on those layers, but what I'm saying holds: the whole thing that public-key encryption deals with basically answers this question with, "you can depend on it".

Comment: `Public key encryption: a message encrypted with a recipient's public key cannot be decrypted by anyone except a possessor of the matching private key` from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_key).

Comment: From that article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Public_key_signing.svg.  You missed the sentence immediately after the one you picked: "Digital signatures: a message signed with a sender's private key can be verified by anyone who has access to the sender's public key".  As you said, we're talking about signing here.  What you're suggesting is that everyone who uses an assembly obtains the private key (which is wrong, since everyone gets the *public* bit)

Comment: I understand, it just sounds a bit funny since you are using "encrypt" and "decrypt" in your explanation when we are really talking about signing. Replace "decrypt" with "verify" and "encrypt" with "sign" in your answer and it makes more sense.

Comment: This is kind of a nice article comparing signatures with encryption: http://www.livinginternet.com/i/is_crypt_sig.htm

Comment: I read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx which uses a much more involved method.  I see in the article that he talks about shortcomings of using public key **tokens**, but I don't see why not use the entire public key.  From the answers so far, that sounds like that's what the public key is for... is the problem in that article that you'd have to try to run the assembly?  (he says, "...but you'd be unable to discover this without checking to see if the assembly passes verification.")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers you question, but here I go:  You can explicitly specify a `PublicKeyToken` in your references, and Fusion (the .net assembly loader) will not load the assembly if the assembly's `PublicKeyToken` does not match.

I think the other answers are specific to public key encrpytion, where my understanding of your question is you're asking about how Fusion handles the `PublicKeyToken` rather than public keys (the assemblies are not encrypted).

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking about the entire public key, not just the token.